# Why is my browser ignoring this javascript? Not executing and no error

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I'm trying follow along with the example on the [getting started](http://c3js.org/gettingstarted.html) page for c3.js.

I have the following html page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "static/css/c3.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/c3.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var chart = c3.generate({
                bindto: '#chart',
                data: {
                  columns: [
                    ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                    ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
                  ]
                }
            });
        </script>
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

However, when I open it in my browser, I only see a blank page. I don't see any errors in the console either. I have been googling for hours and have found no leads. Can someone help me figure out why a graph isn't showing up when the page loads?

If I copy and paste the javascript into the console, then the graph will show up, but not on page load.

```
            var chart = c3.generate({
                bindto: '#chart',
                data: {
                  columns: [
                    ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                    ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
                  ]
                }
            });
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Move the script below the `#chart` element

Comment: It's likely that it does execute, but doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks adeneo! That did the trick! Why does it matter though?

Comment: @quantumbutterfly, it matters because you're trying to bind the chart to an element that does not exist. The html element needs to exist before you can play with it in JS. JS reads top to bottom.